# Converting a for loop to Uppercase

Tags: arrays, for-loop

can't convert this for loop to Uppercase, please help:

```js
for (let i=0; i<=people.length-1; i+=1){
  console.log(people[i])
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear about what you are trying to do. What is your expected result?

Comment: There is not enough information here to help with your question, can you elaborate?

Comment: Please add the people array by editing the question.

Comment: What are you passing in people array? A string?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have input array as string "Hello"
You can use toUpperCase() method to convert it into uppercase.
Read more details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

```js
  const people = "Hello";
  for (let i=0; i<=people.length-1; i+=1){
    console.log(people[i].toUpperCase())
  }
```

Or you can convert whole string into uppercase without a loop as below

```js
const sentence = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';

console.log(sentence.toUpperCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Each string is replaced by its uppercase**

```
for (let i=0; i<=people.length-1; i+=1){
  people[i] = people[i].toUpperCase()
}
console.log(people)
```